# Generate and render a Flask template when Bootstrap tab is changed

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I have a Flask setup serving a template.  The data for this can be nicely split across a few different "sets" which can all be rendered with the same template.  I have inserted Bootstrap tabs which I would like to handle displaying the data for each separate set.  The data my be non-existent or incomplete initially, but will be filled in over time. The hope is that when the user clicks a new Bootstrap tab, it triggers a request for Flask to return the most recent data pertaining to whichever tab was selected.

I have boiled it down to the small example below.  I can successfully generate the Flask request when the tab is changed, but the result isn't triggering a new rendering of the template.

Flask route:

```
@app.route('/test_route', methods=['GET'])
def get_simple():
  set_number_str = request.args.get('set', "mydata-1", type=str)
  set_number = int(set_number_str.split('-')[-1])
  ready = bool(random.getrandbits(1))
  if ready:
    # get_data_for_set(set_number)
    return render_template('simple_template.html',valid=1, data_set=set_number, data_points=[1,2,3])
  else:
    return render_template('simple_template.html', valid=0, data_set=set_number, data_points=[0, 0, 0])
```

Html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="my-tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="set-tabs">
    <li class="active" id="data-1">
      <a href="#mydata-1" data-toggle="tab">Set 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="" id="data-2">
      <a href="#mydata-2" data-toggle="tab">Set 2</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane" id="mydata-1">
        <p>Placeholder 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="mydata-2">
        <p>Placeholder 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    if ({{valid}} == 0) {
        $('#mydata'+'{{data_set}}').html("Waiting on scenario to start...");
    } else {
        $('#mydata'+'{{data_set}}').html("Have some data: " + "{{data_points}}");
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
      var set_id = $(e.target).attr("href");
      $.ajax({
        url: "/test_route",
        type: "get",
        data: {set: set_id},
        success: function(response) {
            $('#mydata-'+set_id).replaceWith(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            console.log(xhr)
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
</script>
```

When I run, the only thing I see is the "Placeholder _" text.

Is this a limitation of Flask/Jinja2 templating or something I'm doing wrong?  If it's the former, do you have any alternative approaches you would recommend?  My key constraint is needing to re-retrieve the data from the server each time as it will change.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the browser debugger to see if your ajax call is being called? Have you tried doing a `console.log` on your function? Have you perhaps tried `$('.tab-pane').click`? Are you getting any JS errors?

Comment: The ajax call is working and I can confirm it is returning a fully rendered template from Flask (done by adding a console.log(response) line inside of the ajax.success function.  My issue is that this isn't triggering the tab content to be updated.

Comment: Try `$('#mydata-' + set_id).html(response);`

Comment: Same result, unfortunately.  Appreciate the help though.